# Turning 1000's of LatLong entries to a map

Tags: web-services, api

What are my options for visualizing a list of 1000's of LatLong coordinates onto a web accessible map?

What are the free and/or paid API options?

(If this question isn't appropriate here, please politely point me to the relevant forum. Thanks!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this is what you are looking for:

http://www.google.com/fusiontables/Home/